# Swift - NSInvalidArgumentException - extremely simple test project still fails

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

All I am trying to do is check if a button was pressed. It works on another view, the one with using viewcontroller.swift but when I changed the controller class name it stoped working. I made sure to change the class name on the storyboard itself. I've seen other posts with the same error but they are always trying to do something more complicated.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class LoginView: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func loginPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("text")
    }
}
```

Here is the log.

```
2015-07-16 09:38:18.468 mybox[44242:318055] -[mybox.LoginView LoginButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffebb032230
2015-07-16 09:38:18.479 mybox[44242:318055] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[mybox.LoginView LoginButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffebb032230'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c8fc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001087fabb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c970ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106bed13c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106beccd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x000000010752fd62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
6   UIKit                               0x000000010764150a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
7   UIKit                               0x00000001076408d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
8   UIKit                               0x000000010757c958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
9   UIKit                               0x000000010757d282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
10  UIKit                               0x0000000107543541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
11  UIKit                               0x0000000107550cdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
12  UIKit                               0x000000010752b59c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106bc3431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106bb92fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106bb8934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106bb8366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d729a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
18  UIKit                               0x000000010752e8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
19  mybox                               0x0000000106950d87 main + 135
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109ce1145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here are some screenshots that might be useful
[image: Proof the class is named correctly]

[image]

Comment: I believe the link between the button action and the @IBAction defined in your `LoginView` is not set correctly. Inside Interface Builder, try to drag `Touch up inside` to File Owner and then select `loginPress`

Comment: Don't include Apple boilerplate code in a question, it just adds clutter. Ex: `viewDidLoad` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Comment: @ObligatorRoy: zaph said right thing alway write useful code only don't add other stuff in question and have you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your method to `LoginButton`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Earlier today I had not set the custom controller class. I changed the class but also deleted the method without deleting the action. When I made a new action the previous action was still tied to the button and caused it to not have anything to call. Thanks @Justa.

Answer (score 0):

I think you write method and then it set with button from storyboard and then rename your method name. so when you are clicking on button that time complier not found old naming method in class thats why it crashed.

you connect "**LoginButton**" this method with button. but that method not exist in class so change your method name in class file or remove method link from storyboard and again set it with "**loginPress**" method.

In short replace your method name with "**LoginButton**"

I think my description will help you to clear what you done wrong in that. hope it will help you.